# Capitalized field name in record

Tags: javascript-objects, record, reason, bucklescript

Is it possible to make a record with a capitalized field name?

something like:

```
[@bs.deriving jsConverter]
type coordinates = {
  X: int,
  Y: int
};
```

The reason I ask is because the js object I'm interfacing with has capitalized keys.

Here's the link to converting record to bucklescript js object:

https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/generate-converters-accessors.html#convert-between-jst-object-and-record

Comment: Glenn's answer is the state of the art in Reason, but just know that you may not need records if you don't need an immutable update syntax. The alternative is using a `Js.t({something})` object type and that will interface perfectly with JS without any conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the fields with an underscore, which will be removed in the generated JS:

```
[@bs.deriving jsConverter]
type coordinates = {
  _X: int,
  _Y: int
};
```

[Documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object.html#invalid-field-names)

That said, I'm not sure it's such a good idea to rely on `jsConverter` for JS interop, since its pretty limited and not generalizable. And while this mangling happens to work here too, it seems like more of a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks again!  Even though not ideal, I still want to try it out for now.  I like working with records and I'm finding writing converters a little annoying... this may bite me later.